# Loading data from sqlite and displaying on ViewPager

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Been trying to load data from sqlite and display it on viewpager without much success.

I have a viewpager with two tabs which should hold data based on the tag_id passed as a parameter of newInstance. There is also an action bar navigation spinner with a list of counties that is used for filter data displayed based on the county_id.

Am able to fetch data from server and save it in the sqlite db but displaying it is the problem. Data is not dispalyed on the first page of the viewpager but it exists in the sqlite. Data for the second is the only one laoded.

Below is my implementation;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.NetworkError;
import com.android.volley.NoConnectionError;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.ServerError;
import com.android.volley.TimeoutError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.app.adapter.CustomCountySpinnerAdapter;
import com.app.adapter.TendersAdapter;
import com.app.database.DBFunctions;
import com.app.externallib.AppController;
import com.app.model.CountyModel;
import com.app.model.PostsModel;
import com.app.utils.AppConstants;
import com.app.utils.PostsListLoader;
import com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.appearance.simple.SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;

public class PublicTendersFragment extends Fragment{

    private static List<PubliTenders> public_tenders;

    public PublicTendersFragment newInstance(String text) {
        PublicTendersFragment mFragment = new PublicTendersFragment();
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putString(AppConstants.TEXT_FRAGMENT, text);
        mFragment.setArguments(mBundle);
        return mFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        public_tenders = new ArrayList<PubliTenders>();
        public_tenders.add(new PubliTenders(14, "County"));
        public_tenders.add(new PubliTenders(15, "National"));

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(
                getActivity(), R.style.StyledIndicators);

        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater
                .cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

        View v = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tenders, container,
                false);

        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new TendersVPAdapter(
                getFragmentManager());
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) v
                .findViewById(R.id.indicator);

        indicator.setViewPager(pager);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    class TendersVPAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public TendersVPAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Tenders.newInstance(public_tenders.get(position).tag_id);

            case 1:
                return Tenders.newInstance(public_tenders.get(position).tag_id);

            default:
                return null;

            }

        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return public_tenders.get(position).tender_type.toUpperCase(Locale
                    .getDefault());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return public_tenders.size();
        }
    }

    public class PubliTenders {
        public int tag_id;
        public String tender_type;

        public PubliTenders(int tag_id, String tender_type) {
            this.tag_id = tag_id;
            this.tender_type = tender_type;
        }
    }

    public static class Tenders extends ListFragment implements
            OnNavigationListener, LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<PostsModel>> {

        boolean mDualPane;
        int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

        // private static View rootView;
        private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
        private ListView lv;
        private View rootView;

        private DBFunctions mapper;
        private CustomCountySpinnerAdapter spinadapter;
        private TendersAdapter mTendersAdapter;

        private static final String ARG_TAG_ID = "tag_id";
        private int tag_id;
        private int mycounty;
        private static final int INITIAL_DELAY_MILLIS = 500;

        private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "BlogsFragment";
        private final String TAG_REQUEST = "BLOG_TAG";
        private JsonArrayRequest jsonArrTendersRequest;

        // private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

        public static Tenders newInstance(int tag_id) {
            Tenders fragment = new Tenders();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt(ARG_TAG_ID, tag_id);
            fragment.setArguments(b);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            tag_id = getArguments().getInt(ARG_TAG_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_headlines_blog,
                    container, false);
            swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.swipeProjectsContainer);
            lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                        int scrollState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    int topRowVerticalPosition = (lv == null || lv
                            .getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : lv.getChildAt(0)
                            .getTop();
                    swipeContainer.setEnabled(topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
                }
            });

            swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    fetchPublicTenders(mycounty);
                }
            });
            swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.blue_dark,
                    R.color.irdac_green, R.color.red_light,
                    R.color.holo_red_light);

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            mapper = new DBFunctions(getActivity());
            mapper.open();

            // initialize AB Spinner
            populateSpinner();

            fetchPublicTenders(mycounty);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

            outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
        }

        private void populateSpinner() {
            try {

                List<CountyModel> counties = new ArrayList<CountyModel>();

                counties = mapper.getAllCounties();

                ActionBar actBar = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity())
                        .getSupportActionBar();
                actBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                actBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

                spinadapter = new CustomCountySpinnerAdapter(getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, counties);

                actBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(spinadapter, this);

            } catch (NullPointerException exp) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public Loader<ArrayList<PostsModel>> onCreateLoader(int arg0,
                Bundle arg1) {
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "On Create Loader");

            return new PostsListLoader(getActivity(), mycounty, tag_id);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<PostsModel>> arg0,
                ArrayList<PostsModel> data) {
            // System.out.println("results " + data.size());
            addToAdapter(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<PostsModel>> arg0) {
            lv.setAdapter(null);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int pos, long arg1) {
            CountyModel mo = spinadapter.getItem(pos);
            this.mycounty = mo.getId();
            refresh(mo.getId());
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tender_title);
            TextView txtRefNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ref_no);
            TextView txtExpiryDate = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.expiry_date);
            TextView txtOrg = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dept_or_org);

            Intent intTenderFullDetails = new Intent(getActivity(),
                    TenderDetailsActivity.class);
            intTenderFullDetails.putExtra(TenderDetailsActivity.TENDER_TITLE,
                    txtTitle.getText().toString().trim());
            intTenderFullDetails.putExtra(TenderDetailsActivity.TENDER_REF_NO,
                    txtRefNo.getText().toString().trim());
            intTenderFullDetails.putExtra(
                    TenderDetailsActivity.TENDER_EXPIRY_DATE, txtExpiryDate
                            .getText().toString().trim());
            intTenderFullDetails.putExtra(TenderDetailsActivity.TENDER_ORG,
                    txtOrg.getText().toString().trim());
            // intTenderFullDetails.putExtra(TenderDetailsActivity.TENDER_DESC,
            // Lorem);
            startActivity(intTenderFullDetails);

        }

        private void fetchPublicTenders(final int county_id) {
            swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);

            Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(AppConstants.postsUrl).buildUpon();
            builder.appendQueryParameter("tag_id", Integer.toString(tag_id));

            System.out.println("fetchPublicTenders with tag_id " + tag_id
                    + " and county_id " + county_id);

            jsonArrTendersRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(builder.toString(),
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            if (response.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                    try {
                                        JSONObject tender_item = response
                                                .getJSONObject(i);
                                        mapper.createPost(
                                                tender_item.getInt("id"),
                                                tender_item.getInt("tag_id"),
                                                tender_item.getInt("county_id"),
                                                tender_item.getInt("sector_id"),
                                                tender_item.getString("title"),
                                                tender_item.getString("slug"),
                                                tender_item.getString("content"),
                                                tender_item
                                                        .getString("reference_no"),
                                                tender_item
                                                        .getString("expiry_date"),
                                                tender_item
                                                        .getString("organization"),
                                                tender_item
                                                        .getString("image_url"),
                                                tender_item
                                                        .getString("created_at"));
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                                    refresh(county_id);
                                }
                            } else {

                                if (swipeContainer.isShown()) {
                                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                                }
                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                            "Sorry! No results found",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                    System.out.println(npe);
                                }

                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity(),
                                            "Network Error. Cannot refresh list",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                    System.err.println(npe);
                                }
                                if (swipeContainer.isShown()) {
                                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                                }
                                refresh(county_id);
                            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {

                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity(),
                                            "Problem Connecting to Server. Try Again Later",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                    System.err.println(npe);
                                }
                                if (swipeContainer.isShown()) {
                                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                                }
                            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                            "No Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                    System.err.println(npe);
                                }
                            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                                try {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            getActivity()
                                                    .getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Timeout Error. Try Again Later",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                                    System.err.println(npe);
                                }
                            }
                            if (swipeContainer.isShown()) {
                                swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
                    return headers;
                }
            };

            // Set a retry policy in case of SocketTimeout & ConnectionTimeout
            // Exceptions. Volley does retry for you if you have specified the
            // policy.
            jsonArrTendersRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(20),
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            jsonArrTendersRequest.setTag(TAG_REQUEST);
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrTendersRequest);
        }

        public void refresh(int county_id) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("myconty", county_id);
            if (isAdded()) {
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, b, this);
            }

        }

        private void addToAdapter(ArrayList<PostsModel> plist) {
            mTendersAdapter = new TendersAdapter(rootView.getContext(), plist);
            SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter swingBottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(
                    mTendersAdapter);
            swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(lv);
            assert swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.getViewAnimator() != null;
            swingBottomInAnimationAdapter.getViewAnimator()
                    .setInitialDelayMillis(INITIAL_DELAY_MILLIS);
            setListAdapter(swingBottomInAnimationAdapter);
            mTendersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }


}
```

And this is the PostsListLoader class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader;

import com.app.database.DBFunctions;
import com.app.model.PostsModel;

public class PostsListLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<PostsModel>> {
    private DBFunctions mapper;
    private ArrayList<PostsModel> myPostsModel;
    private int county_id;
    private int tag_id;

    public PostsListLoader(Context context, int county_id, int tag_id) {
        super(context);
        mapper = new DBFunctions(getContext());
        mapper.open();

        this.county_id = county_id;
        this.tag_id = tag_id;

    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<PostsModel> loadInBackground() {
        String query_string = AppConstants.KEY_COUNTY_ID + " = " + county_id
                + " AND " + AppConstants.KEY_TAG_ID + " = " + tag_id;
        myPostsModel = mapper.getPosts(query_string);
        return myPostsModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(ArrayList<PostsModel> data) {
        if (isReset()) {
            // An async query came in while the loader is stopped. We
            // don't need the result.
            if (data != null) {
                onReleaseResources(data);
            }
        }
        List<PostsModel> oldNews = data;

        myPostsModel = data;

        if (isStarted()) {
            // If the Loader is currently started, we can immediately
            // deliver its results.
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with
        // 'oldNews' if needed; now that the new result is delivered we
        // know that it is no longer in use.
        if (oldNews != null) {
            onReleaseResources(oldNews);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to start the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (myPostsModel != null) {
            // If we currently have a result available, deliver it
            // immediately.
            deliverResult(myPostsModel);
        }

        if (takeContentChanged() || myPostsModel == null) {
            // If the data has changed since the last time it was loaded
            // or is not currently available, start a load.
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to stop the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
        cancelLoad();
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to cancel a load.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCanceled(ArrayList<PostsModel> news) {
        super.onCanceled(news);

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'news'
        // if needed.
        onReleaseResources(news);
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to completely reset the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();

        // Ensure the loader is stopped
        onStopLoading();

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps'
        // if needed.
        if (myPostsModel != null) {
            onReleaseResources(myPostsModel);
            myPostsModel = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to take care of releasing resources associated with an
     * actively loaded data set.
     */
    protected void onReleaseResources(List<PostsModel> news) {
    }

}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Any help  will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: i dont see anywhere you are using any sqlite api calls...

Comment: @pskink The PostsListLoader class is the one responsible for making the sqlite calls. I have updated the post to include this class